# Is my $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for this rational function limit correct?

Tags: limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to prove

$$\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x^2+x+1}{3x+3}=-1$$

Rough Work:

$$|f(x)-L| = \left| \frac{x^2+x+1}{3x+3}+1\right|= \left| \frac{x^2+4x+4}{3x+3}\right|=\frac{|x+2|^2}{|3x+3|}$$

If we restrict

$$|x+2| < 0.5$$

then

$$-0.5 < x+2 < 0.5$$
$$\implies -4.5 < 3x+3 < -1.5$$

so

$$|3x+3|>1.5$$

meaning

$$\frac{|x+2|^2}{|3x+3|} < \frac{|x+2|^2}{\frac 32}$$ 
$$\implies \frac{|x+2|^2}{|3x+3|} < \frac{2|x+2|^2}{3}$$
(*)

suggesting we take

$$\delta = \sqrt{\frac 32 \epsilon}$$

Proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Set $\delta = $ min $\left\{ 0.5, \sqrt{\frac 32 \epsilon} \right\}$.

Assume $|x+2| < \delta$.

$$|f(x)-L| = \frac{|x+2|^2}{|3x+3|}$$

Because $|x+2| < 0.5$, by (*),

$$\frac{|x+2|^2}{|3x+3|} < \frac{2|x+2|^2}{3}$$

And because $|x+2| < \sqrt{\frac 32 \epsilon}$,

$$\frac{2|x+2|^2}{3} < \frac{2\sqrt{\frac 32 \epsilon}^2}{3}$$
$$\implies \frac{2|x+2|^2}{3} < \epsilon$$

Comment: Yes, it looks good.